# Trying To Use A PHP Header with an IFrame

Tags: php, html, css, iframe, scroll

I am trying to add a blog to my website and I decided I would just create a google blog and use a full screen Iframe to display it on my page. It works fine but then I decided to add the websites header. So now I have the header followed by the Iframe but I would like to be able to treat the header & Iframe as one single page. Right now the header is always visible and I can scroll through the Iframe with the header always showing above it which is not the most visibly pleasant experience. Here is the code:

```
<?php
include("header.php");
?>  
    <html> 
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body
        {
            margin:   0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        #iframe1
        {
            height:   80%;
            left:     0px;
            position: absolute;
            top:      180px;
            width:    100%;

        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <iframe id="iframe1" src="http://xxxx.blogspot.com/" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

**Here is the header code:**

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta name="google-site-verification"=xxx />
 <script type="text/javascript">

 var _gaq = _gaq || [];
 _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-26023641-1']);
 _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

 (function() {
 var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async =  true;
 ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') +  '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
 })();

</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>xxx &ndash; <?php if ($page != 'Home') { echo $page; }  else { echo 'xxxxs'; } ?></title>
<meta name="description" content="xxx." />
<meta name="keywords" content="xxx<?php echo $tags; ?>" />

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lightview/js/excanvas/excanvas.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/external.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lightview/js/spinners/spinners.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lightview/js/lightview/lightview.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/coop/cse/brand?form=cse-search-box"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/hub.css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/lightview/css/lightview/lightview.css"/>


<!--[if IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie7styles.css" /><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 6]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie6styles.css"  /><![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 6]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie6styles.css" /><![endif]-->

<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/ico" />

</head>
<body>

<div id="header">
<a id="logo" href="/"></a>
<ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="xx">xx</a></li>
        <li><a href="xx">xx</a></li>
        <li><a href="xx">xx</a></li>
        <li><a href="xx">xx</a></li>
        <li><a href="xx">xx</a></li>
        <li><a href="xx">xx</a></li>
        <li><a href="xx">xx</a></li>
        <li><a href="xx">xx</a></li>
        <li><a href="xx">xx</a></li>
        <li><a href="xx">xx</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="content">
```

Comment: whats in your header?

Comment: This code tell us nothing. You need to explain what exactly `header.php` is and does, because right now... the code looks "fine".

Comment: Sorry about that, I have added the header code

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your scroll bar is within the iframe and disabled on the main page body, so scrolling is only scrolling within the iframe and not your whole page.  Remove overflow: hidden from your page body and make it so your iframe stretches its height to fit its contents.  That way, the scrollbar you see on the page would scroll your entire page instead of just the iframe.

Comment: But it does not treat the page as "one page". For instance, the header still occupies the top portion of the page at all times. And you still need to scroll within the iframe.